# What dependency should i Add If I have 1000 Test data in API restAssured

Tags: api, testing, automation, ui-automation, rest-assured

How can I handle 1000 test data in RestAssured API testing?

Which dependency should be added for handling bulk test data in RestAssured API automation?

How to manage large volumes of test data in RestAssured API testing?

Comment: You don't sepecify what data format you are having and how to use the data.

Answer (score 0):

**To handle 1000 test data in RestAssured API testing**, you can prepare your test data in such a way by creating a dataset containing 1000 sets of test data, with each set representing a unique test scenario. This could be done using an Excel sheet, CSV file, JSON file, or any other format that suits your needs.

Use a library or framework to read the test data from the file into your test code using a loop to iterate through each set of test data. For example, you can use Apache POI library for Excel files, or any JSON parsing library for JSON files.Within the loop, use RestAssured library to send API requests and verify the responses for each set of test data. You can define your API requests, headers, query parameters, request bodies, and assertions based on the test data for each iteration.

**You can add the relevant dependencies** to your project's build configuration file (e.g., Maven's pom.xml or Gradle's build.gradle) to use these libraries.

**To manage large volumes of test data** in RestAssured API testing, consider the Data-driven testing.